# Updating attribute value in Loop - Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to make a image slide from left to write and right to left infinitely in a loop in my react component.

I am not able to change the left property of the style attribute.

Here is the relevant piece of code

```
let lastRight = 0;
let multiplier = 1;
const images = [One, Two, Three, Four];

class ImageStream extends Component {

  state = {
      position: [0, 640, 1280, 1920]
  };

  changeLeft() {
    if (lastRight > 2000) {
      multiplier = -1;
    } else if (lastRight < -600) {
      multiplier = 1;
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < this.state.position.length; i++) {
      this.state.position[i] = (this.state.position[i] + (multiplier * 1));
      lastRight = this.state.position[i];
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.intervalID = setInterval(this.changeLeft.bind(this), 200);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    // use intervalId from the state to clear the interval
    clearInterval(this.intervalId);
  }

  renderImage(imageUrl, index) {
    return (
      <img
        src={imageUrl}
        style={{ left: this.state.position[index] }}
        key={index + "_image"}
      />
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div id="image-scroll" className="mt-4">
        {images.map((imageUrl, index) => this.renderImage(imageUrl, index))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ImageStream;
```

What I am expecting is that the left property of the style attribute of the image changes because the position arrays is changing regularly.

I am fairly new to React and would love to know if I am doing this wrong/right.

Thank you in advance for looking into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were not using `setState` to change the `state`, also tweaked a few numbers and CSS to get the things running. Do check it out

```js
let lastRight = 0;
let multiplier = 1;
const images = ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four"];

class ImageStream extends React.Component {

  state = {
      position: [0, 640, 1280, 1920]
  };

  changeLeft() {
    if (lastRight > 2000) {
      multiplier = -1;
    } else if (lastRight < -600) {
      multiplier = 1;
    }
    let posArr = [...this.state.position]
    for (let i = 0; i < posArr.length; i++) {
      let pos = posArr[i]
      , newPos = pos + (multiplier * 10)
      
      posArr[i] = newPos     
      this.setState({ position: posArr })
      lastRight = newPos
    }
    
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.changeLeft = this.changeLeft.bind(this)
    this.intervalID = setInterval(this.changeLeft, 10);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    // use intervalId from the state to clear the interval
    clearInterval(this.intervalId);
  }

  renderImage(imageUrl, index) {
    return (
      <img
        src={imageUrl}
        style={{ left: this.state.position[index] }}
        key={index + "_image"}
      />
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div id="image-scroll" className="mt-4">
        {images.map((imageUrl, index) => this.renderImage(imageUrl, index))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <ImageStream />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```css
img{ position: relative; width: 100px; height: 100px; outline: 1px solid blue;}
```

```html
<div id="react"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Do you know what state mutation is and why you should not do it?

Comment: Yep, made it immutable